# Updated to iOS 17. iPhone resets GPS location after disconnecting from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I’ve just updated my iPhone to iOS 17, and since then the device keeps on resetting GPS location set in Xcode after disconnecting from my desktop.

When I check location on iPhone, at first, it greys out, then it goes back to my real GPS.

Is there any way to simulate GPS location permanently in Xcode (until reboot)?

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: I suspect that this is a loophole that Apple has deliberately closed

Comment: @Paulw11, what makes you think so, if I may ask?

Comment: Because undocumented behaviour that has existed for many years has suddenly changed.

Answer (score -1):

Responding to the following question...

> "Is there any way to simulate GPS location permanently (until
> reboot)?"

My Honest response: You can change the location of your iPhone without jailbreaking it by two ways, the first one being **Desktop Location Spoofers** and the second one **using a Hardware Dongle**.

1. *Desktop Location Spoofers* - You can actually find some several applications like iSpoofer, iTools, or even Dr.Fone. If you're choosing "Dr.Fone" you will need to launch it and then go to "Teleport Mode".
2. *Using a Hardware Dongle* - You can use a hardware dongle connected to your Iphone. If you don't know what dongle should you buy I honestly recommend GFaker or iTeleporter. Once the dongle is connected, you can grant it the needed permissions on your iPhone. Later, you can use their apps to change the location of your iPhone on any installed app.

I hope I helped you in one way or another.

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately, that’s not a fix for Xcode, which I’m looking for.

Comment: @matador.lining did you find a fix?

Comment: @user3440639, unfortunately, I did not. Debug > Pause makes the GPS location stay longer, but not permanently. Did you have any success?

Comment: @user3440639, I can confirm that there is no such problem on iOS16, which doesn’t support remote control from Xcode.